# How to resume error handling from the calling function while in a subfunction in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

When I write in VBA for Word or Excel, I typically have an error handler in my main function and call several subs from it, and most of the time, I want subs' messages to get caught in the main function. Typically everything works great with this strategy, and it mimics what I'm used to in C++.

However, I run into trouble when I need a different type of error handling in one or two subs.

For example, when I need to turn on `Resume Next` for the sake of checking if an object fails and is set to nothing. When I want to turn error handling on, my `MainErrorHandler` is now out of scope.

```
Sub Main()
    On Error GoTo MainErrorHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call OpenFile
    Call SubWithOwnErrorHandling

    'Do more stuff

    GoTo CleanExit

MainErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description

CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub OpenFile()

    On Error Resume Next
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileLocation & fileName, 1)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler ' Label Not Defined!

    If objFile Is Nothing Then
        Call Err.Raise(2009, , "Out File doesn’t exist.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Likewise, when I want to have a sub handle errors locally and occasionally elevate an error, I'm not sure how exactly to do that.

```
Sub SubWithOwnErrorHandling()
    On Error GoTo SubErrorHandler

    isReallyBad = True

    If isReallyBad Then
        Call Err.Raise(2020, , "Error that needs to cause application to exit!")
    Else
        Call Err.Raise(2001, , "Error that just needs the function to exit!")
    End If

SubErrorHandler:
    On Error GoTo MainErrorHandler ' Label Not Defined!

    If Err.Number = 2020 Then
        Call Err.Raise(2020, , Err.Description)
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to accomplish for either case?

Comment: In your first example clearing the `On Error Resume Next` in `OpenFile` using `On Error Goto 0` will not affect the error handling in your calling Sub.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: In the second example remove the `On Error GoTo MainErrorHandler`: any error you Raise inside `SubErrorHandler` will be passed back to the calling sub.

Comment: I see it now:  "However, if the procedure in which the error occurs does not have an error handler, VBA looks backwards through the procedure calls which lead to the erroneous code. For example if procedure A calls B and B calls C, and A is the only procedure with an error handler, if an error occurs in procedure C, code execution is immediately transferred to the error handler in procedure A, skipping the remaining code in B."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are always local.

`On Error` is always local too - heck, its deprecated ancestor was `On Local Error`!

So you can't `GoTo`-jump between procedure scopes (THANK GOD!!)

This means at any given time, there's only ever one of two things the run-time can do `On Error`:

- Jump to a local error handler
- Blow up the current stack frame and see if the caller handles it
- [ignore the error and happily keep running blindfolded under blue skies and sunshine]

That third point, you guessed it, is what `On Error Resume Next` does.

One critical error you've done, is specifying an `On Error` statement *inside an error-handling subroutine*, and the error-handling subroutine runs regardless of whether you're in an error state or not. That makes following execution extremely confusing, even if that label was legal. `Exit Sub` or `Exit Function` (or heck, `Exit Property`, depending on what's your scope) *before* the handler, and make sure error-handling code is only ever hit *in an error state*.

#### Resetting error handling

So, one thing you want to do, is to *reset* error handling - here:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileLocation & fileName, 1)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler ' Label Not Defined!
```

You know `objFSO.OpenTextFile` can possibly blow up, and you want to handle it yourself, i.e. deal with the `objFile Is Nothing` possibiilty manually. You can absolutely do that, but then what you need is this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileLocation & fileName, 1)
On Error GoTo 0
```

`On Error GoTo 0` resets error handling, i.e. the next instruction to throw an error *will* bubble up the call stack, until everything goes up in flames.

#### Custom Errors

The next thing you want to do, is to raise custom errors.

> ```
> If isReallyBad Then
>     Call Err.Raise(2020, , "Error that needs to cause application to exit!")
> Else
>     Call Err.Raise(2001, , "Error that just needs the function to exit!")
> End If
> ```

That's pretty easy actually - but it's easier with an `Enum`:

```
Public Enum AppCustomError
    ERR_ReallyBad = vbObjectError + 42
    ERR_ReallyReallyBad
    ERR_VeryReallyTerriblyBad
    ERR_YouGetTheIdea
End Enum
```

The `vbObjectError` constant ensures that your custom error numbering doesn't step on toes; your error numbers will all be negative - and with an `Enum` for each possible error you can throw, you don't need to care what the actual error number is, so you let the enum member mechanics do their thing (e.g. `ERR_ReallyReallyBad` will be `ERR_ReallyBad + 1`, automatically).

Then you can do this (assuming you're in a class module - otherwise replace `TypeName(Me)` with some string literal, or skip it):

```
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If isReallyBad Then
        Err.Raise ERR_VeryReallyTerriblyBad, TypeName(Me), "Blow up the app!"
    Else
        Err.Raise ERR_ReallyBad, TypeName(Me), "Blow up this function!"
    End If
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    With Err
        Select Case .Number
            Case ERR_VeryReallyTerriblyBad
                .Raise .Number 'rethrow
            Case ERR_ReallyBad
                'function blew up, we're done here.
            '...
        End Select
    End With
```

And then the calling code, which has its own error-handling subroutine, can decide that it can't deal with `ERR_VeryReallyTerriblyBad`, and just blow everything up by rethrowing:

```
    Exit Sub
MainErrorHandler:
    With Err
        Select Case .Number
            Case ERR_VeryReallyTerriblyBad
                .Raise .Number 'rethrow
            Case Else
                MsgBox .Description
        End Select
    End With
```

Comment: Great explanation, and nice suggestion for enum use.  One thing I would point out  for those reading this later, when resetting error handing after temporality turning on/off OERN in the same function as the Error Handler, you do need to call On Error Goto ErrorHandler instead of On Error Goto 0.

Comment: @CassieD thanks! also note `Err.Raise Err.Number` is all you need to rethrow an error =)